# Jenkins ssh issue after upgrading to 2.36.1

Tags: jenkins, ssh, plugins, jenkins-agent

After upgrading the jenkins version to 2.36.1 the agent nodes are not connecting to the remote servers from the given key path for those servers in the global configuration. The publish over ssh plug-in and build agents plug-in are installed. From controller node they are connecting when the job is running but if the job gets triggered from agent node they are not connecting

I tried updating the ssh plugins that are available. But still facing the same issue

Comment: Jenkins 2.36.1?  No such release & 5.5 years old if it existed. Also list plugin versions AND any errors, logs.

Comment: I guess he mean to say  2.361.1 version of Jenkins